# Slow page rendering with PdfBox Android

Tags: android, pdfbox

I'm using PdfBox 1.8 ported to android (https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android) to render pages in an app.

The 7mb document I'm using takes 8 seconds to load, then each page takes 0.5-2 seconds to render.

I've tried out other PDF viewer apps and libraries, and they are all capable of loading and rendering the same document instantly.

Strangely enough, after converting that file to the RGB color space it now renders the pages instantly. Although this might be to do with the file structure being modified, as its also been linearized and the operators seem to have been compressed.

I've analysed and profiled the differences between the rendering the two documents:

1. In the original document, the garbage collector runs for a long time.
2. In the original document, the log keeps printing: "W/System: A resource failed to call end.".
3. The new document has way fewer graphical operators.

I'm wondering if anyone might know what the cause of this is, and/or how to fix it.

EDIT:

Original document:
<edit: redacted>

New document (converted to RGB colour space):
<edit: redacted>

Looking at the function calls wall clock times in the profiler, there aren't any particular bottlenecks. It might just be that the way PdfBox handles graphics operators is really slow, which would explain why the new document loads faster as it only has around 2 operators per page as opposed to the many dozen of the original.

Comment: Please share the two PDF files. I can't help much (I'm not involved in the android version) but I could look at the PDF to tell about the differences.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I've added google drive links. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks. In the RGB file these are just images, i.e. it has been rendered. The original file is rather complex, several levels, lots of vector graphics, many tiny images, forms etc. PDFBox for desktop renders the "slow" file in < 1 second. One factor is that the android version is somewhat behind, and the last commit is from 2019.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr If I ported some of the new code over, do you think that could be worthwhile? If so, are there any particular changes that improve performance?

Comment: The android project is probably hundreds, if not thousands commits behind. This would be a work of weeks, maybe months. What you could try is to run a profiler to see where the rendering is slow, and then investigate what files are affected, then concentrate on these.